# Listing index uses wrong dashes

Tags: listings, punctuation

When generating an index of all my Listings, the library seems to use the wrong dashes to connect words:

*Expected*

```
Unported-2.0-Graphic
```

*Actual*

```
Unported—2.0—Graphic
```

In the title of the listings, I used the normal dash `-`, so it has to be somewhere in the library that the double dashes `--` are created.

As this is not really a big issue, but totally wrong typography, I'd very much like to change it to the correct way.

*MWE*

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{caption=\lstname}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\begin{lstlisting}[name=Unported-2.0-Graphic]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Done. Sorry for forgetting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listings` package defines an internal command for replacements within filenames.  One of these replacements replaces `-` with `\textendash`.  You can redefine this command to make the hyphens actual hyphens:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@filenamerpl{_\textunderscore $\textdollar}
\makeatother
\lstset{caption=\lstname}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\begin{lstlisting}[name=Unported-2.0-Graphic]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]